# add values to mysql new field

Tags: mysql

i have a table with some fields

i add one more an 'id' field and i want to automatic take values 0,1,2...etc

whats the command to do this?

thnx

Comment: The parameter you mean is called autoincrement and serial in some other dialects. Most editors like SQLPro (on MacOS X) or phpmyadmin (webbased) just have a checkbox for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table t(
   a varchar(10) not null
  ,b varchar(10) not null
);

insert into t(a,b) values('a1', 'b1');
insert into t(a,b) values('a2', 'b2');
insert into t(a,b) values('a3', 'b3');

alter table t add id int not null auto_increment primary key;

select * from t;


+----+----+----+
| a  | b  | id |
+----+----+----+
| a1 | b1 |  1 |
| a2 | b2 |  2 |
| a3 | b3 |  3 |
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: thats right...what if i want id starts from zero and not from 1 ?

thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Set `AUTO_INCREMENT` to this column.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE example_autoincrement (
         id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
         data VARCHAR(100)
       );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: so the correct answer for the existing table is

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;